# OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, datetime

Thanks for taking the time to look and help me out.  I am driving myself nuts with what seems to be a very easy insert operation but I can't seem to get passed this part.  Here is what I have for code:

```
 protected void InsertIntoMaterialDB()
    {
        ToroGeneral toro = new ToroGeneral();

        // Grab connection string.
        string conString = toro.GetOracle1ConnectionString();
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO MATERIALMOVEREQUEST (ORIGINATOR, REQUESTDATE, PARTNUMBER, REQUESTQTY, MOVEFROM, MOVETO, COMPLETEDBY, COMPLETION_DATE, COMMENTS, RESPONSETIME) "
                               + "values (:Originator, :RequestDate, :PartNumber, :RequestQty, :MoveFrom, :MoveTo, :CompletedBy, :CompletionDate, :ResponseTime, :Comments)";

        using(OracleConnection conn1 = new OracleConnection(conString))
        {    
             conn1.Open();
             OracleCommand cmd = conn1.CreateCommand();
             OracleTransaction myTrans;
             cmd.CommandText = insertQuery;
             myTrans = conn1.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
             cmd.Transaction = myTrans;

             if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
             {
                  cmd.Connection.Open();
             }

             DateTime rDate = DateTime.Parse(RequestDateTB.Text);
             DateTime cDate = DateTime.Parse(CompDateTB.Text);

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Originator", OracleType.VarChar).Value = OriginatorTB.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RequestDate", OracleType.DateTime).Value = rDate;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartNumber", OracleType.VarChar).Value = PartNumber.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RequestQty", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(RequestQuantity.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MoveFrom", OracleType.VarChar).Value = MoveFromTB.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MoveTo", OracleType.VarChar).Value = MoveToTB.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CompletedBy", OracleType.VarChar).Value = CompletedByTB.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CompletionDate", OracleType.DateTime).Value = cDate;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ResponseTime", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(RespTimeTB.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comments", OracleType.VarChar).Value = CommentsTB.Text;

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // THIS THROWS AN EXCEPTION.
             cmd.Transaction.Commit();
        }

    }
```

I was able to get everything working except for the two 'DATE' type fields REQUESTDATE and COMPLETION_DATE.  I don't know what I am doing wrong except for that when it gets to the ExecuteNonQuery() call it throws an exception.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the exception? Also, If you execute the query with same inputs on Oracle, does that get executed?

Comment: ORA-01740: missing double quote in identifier

EDIT: I think I am missing "" or '' in my INSERT statement now that I think about it.

Comment: ORA-01843: not a valid month when pointing to :RequestDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into a similar issue in the past.  Use the To_Date function to convert the string to a date oracle will recognize.

```
INSERT INTO MATERIALMOVEREQUEST (ORIGINATOR, REQUESTDATE, PARTNUMBER, REQUESTQTY, MOVEFROM, MOVETO, COMPLETEDBY, COMPLETION_DATE, COMMENTS, RESPONSETIME) "
                           + "values (:Originator, To_Date(:RequestDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'), :PartNumber, :RequestQty, :MoveFrom, :MoveTo, :CompletedBy, To_Date(:CompletionDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'), :ResponseTime, :Comments)";
```

Then in your parameters set the value to a string.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RequestDate", OracleType.VarChar).Value = rDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: This assumes the user account has alter session at the database level which almost never occurs in production for standard users.  I would have to say this is a less than desirable answer.

Comment: I would think a user who has rights to manipulate data has the ability to cause much more damage than a user to have alter session rights at the database.  The session alteration lasts only as long as the connection to the database is active.  When connecting to the database via Benthic (or your tool of choice) you have the ability to set the date format, which uses the alter session command.

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:77552825928548  This is just one place that advises as such.  There are many more.....

Comment: Answer has been updated.  Looking back at it, I think this is a cleaner solution anyway, less traffic to the database.  It is a strange quirk in the instance of oracle I am working and this seems to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

For the Date fields you probably want to use `OracleType.DateTime` and pass a DateTime value that you generate by parsing the input string, e.g.:

```
AddWithValue("CompletedBy", OracleType.DateTime).Value = 
              DateTime.ParseExact(...CompletedByTB.Text...);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Joe said above, I noticed a couple of things :-

a) You are opening a transaction but never rollbacking it in case of any exception. You may want to enclose this with try catch statement and rollback the transaction in case of exception and commit otherwise.

b) You should always use the using block around the connection objects (I just edited your code in the question). That way you don't have to close and dispose connection explicitly. This is because all connection provider types (including OracleConnection) implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface via their base class "DbConnection".

Comment: Thanks for editing that for me.  Makes total sense now that I think about it.  I will try Joe's solution and post my results.

Comment: "You may want to enclose this with try catch statement and rollback the transaction in case of exception and commit otherwise" - or more concisely, put it in a using block (Dispose will roll back the transaction if it hasn't been committed).